# How to resolve below error with statsmodel?

Tags: python, attributeerror, holtwinters

I am using `statsmodel` version 0.9.0 and Jupiter notebook to run `SimpleExpSmooting` and Holtwinters model and getting attribute error `_get_prediction_index` for both.

Tried reinstalling the statsmodel package

```
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import SimpleExpSmoothing
fit2 = SimpleExpSmoothing(np.asarray(Train['Count']))
fit2._index = pd.to_datetime(Train.index)
pred = fit2.fit()
y_hat_avg['SES'] = pred.forecast(len(valid))
```

Expected results would be correct forecast. Instead getting the error below:

> AttributeError: 'SimpleExpSmoothing' object has no attribute
>   '_get_prediction_index'.

Any pointers please, TIA.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the `Train` dataset? Please share the full Traceback error message.

Comment: Perhaps, you should try re-installing the package with the latest version. Refer: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/4225